# import picklist values from excel

Tags: picklist, custom-field, excel

Hello everybody I was wondering if it is possible bringing to Salesforce an excel that contains picklist values and save it in a picklist field.
Because I have like 500 excel rows and I have to save them in a picklist field
If it is possible could anybody do an example?
Thanks

Comment: Check this link https://medium.com/@apps.mohite/how-to-load-a-large-number-of-picklist-values-in-salesforce-ant-and-excel-94bf12886fd8

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import an excel into a picklist directly but you should find that you can just copy/paste the values that you want from your excel into the 'add picklist values' screen as long as they are text values.

If you have trouble copying and pasting directly from excel you can try pasting to notepad first to make sure all the values are plain text and paste into Salesforce from there.